# Script not able to generate files for backup file

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, function

I'm new to shell scripting and I trying to write a script that:

- Prompts for a directory
- Loops through the directory
- If it find files it then backs them up using a function in the script
- Creates a backup

I just created a file called file.bak for all the files to be copied into if they were found.

```
#!/bin/bash


function backup()
{
cp"$name" >> file.bak
}


#Main Script
echo -n "Please enter a directory name: "
read name
directory="/home/shawn"
if [ -O "$name" ] || [ -G "$name" ]
then
backup
else
echo "$name has no files."
fi
```

Comment: For meaningful answers, you might want to explain what you mean by "create a backup"; do you want to copy each file to a new file, or to create a single file containing the concatenation of your source files?

Comment: Copy each file to a new file which is file.bak

Comment: So there is only one output file name. What if the directory contains more than one file?

Comment: Perhaps it would be best if you showed us an expected list of files before backing up, and after backing up.

Comment: Write a script (called backupfile.sh) that consists two parts: 

A function called backup that has parameter, the name of the file to backup
A main section, which prompts users to enter a directory, and then loop through the items in the directory. If it is a file, it calls the backup function to create a backup copy of the file.

Comment: ^ This is what my instructor sent me. So I'm going off this.

Comment: @DSH72 We're not here to do your homework.  You may want to double check the academic standards at your school to make sure asking for help here isn't considered cheating.

Comment: Never asked somebody to do my homework. I supplied what I had.

Comment: there's a clue on what you need to do in your homework assignment: `and then loop through the items in the directory. If it is a file, it calls the backup function to create a backup copy of the file`.  You're missing this loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured it out on my own. All were good answers but none produced the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this probably doesn't do what you mean to do:

```
cp"$name" >> file.bak
```

This will attempt to call a command whose first two characters are
`cp`, and the rest are the value of `$name`. Such a command probably
doesn't exist.

Adding a space doesn't solve the problem:

```
cp "$name" >> file.bak
```

This will call the command `cp` with a single parameter (which is an
invalid way to call it), and append whatever this command prints on
stdout into a file named `file.bak`. You probably want something
like `cp "$name" file.bak` or perhaps `cat "$name" >> file.bak`

The tests using `-O` and `-G` don't make a lot of sense either; the
error message you are printing does not really match what those
operators check for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Please enter a directory name: "
read name
find $name -type f -exec cp {} {}.bak \;
```